# PHP namespace in relation to file structure

Tags: php, namespaces

I have yet to find a clear answer on how PHP namespaces work in relation to the file strucutre

If I have some code say

```
<?PHP

namespace Go/Project

Use Foo/Bar/Dog

class cat extends dog
{

.....

}

?>
```

What does the file structure for something like this look like and do I need to reflect what I am doing in the namspaces and the imports in the file structure or do I need to add some include()s in there.

Comment: Hi Aaron! I think an example of Zend Framework2 tells everything. https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Barcode/Renderer/Pdf.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your autoloader.
Some frameworks use standard of [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md), some not use. You can write your application without any autoloader and write namespaces independent of your files structure.

For example you can declare namespace `Acme/Foo/Bar/Do/For/Me/Some/Thing` in `index.php` of your DocumentRoot and all classes declared in this file will be stored under this namespace.

But if you want to not write in every file `require` statements for your files you may want to write your autoloader function and make dependence between files structure and namespaces structure.

Comment: Thank you. Helping me realize there were things like autoloaders really helped clear things up.